# ASP.NET MVC jquery datepicker bug

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, input

I'm trying to set default value for text input, but when doing this

```
<input type="text" id="dateTo" name="to" class="datepick" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")" />
```

i'm getting some like this `2015-41-26`

and when i'm set jquery picker time format like this

```
$(function () {
    $(".datepick").datepicker({ gotoCurrent: true, dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", firstDay: 1 });
});
```

date format - like a this `2015-01-26` (TG with correct date)

How to solve both piece of one problem with datepicker.

Comment: Q: Why 4 digit *and* 2 digit years? Why not just 4 digit years for both?

Comment: To mock up a repro, can you do a `save-as` from your browser of the page's raw HTML and stick it in a JSFiddle? That will help testing the date-picker problem (please fix the `mm => MM` first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server-side `mm` is the minutes, not the months :)

In .Net a 2 digit month is `MM` (capital `M`s).

e.g. change it to:

```
@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: You are right(i get lost it) - but when i select a datepicker i getting exception like this `Exception was thrown at line 19, column 49713 in http://localhost:46960/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError` may be this happened because dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" != "@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")